# A hashtable with a 1.0 maxLoad factors, time complexity

Tags: java, hashtable, time-complexity

Just a quick question to confirm my thoughts,

The complexity of a hash table using a load factor of 1.0 would be quadratic time shown with the following notation O(n^2).

This would be because of having to continuously resize and insert over and over. Please correct me if im wrong.

Thanks

Comment: O(n^2) does not sound right for any hash table.

Comment: Hm, it depends if your Map reaches a steady state. I doubt you would have a ever growing map in real life. And if you set the initial size correct it would not have to grow. The problem of the load factor is more along the line of having a much higher chance of hash conflicts.

Comment: O(n^2) would require an infinite load factor, not a 1.0 load factor.

Answer (score 2):

The worst case scenarios for searching, inserting, and deleting for a hash table will almost always be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you mean open addressing. With separate chaining, complexity of all operations will still be O(1).